# Selecting Count based on 1 field or another - Conditional Count

Tags: mysql, count

I have 2 fields in the table manager_id and on_behalf_manager_id actually while filling this form, or rather inserting the table one of these will be filled and the other will be 0. Now I need the count where both manager_id or on_behalf_manager_id are same, The structure of the table is as below:

```
Table : Feedbacks
id    manager_id     on_behalf_manager_id    score    created     status
1     2              0                       20       2017-08-17  1
2     2              0                       21       2017-08-18  1
3     0              2                       20       2017-08-17  1
4     1              0                       10       2017-08-17  1
5     2              0                       17       2017-08-17  1
6     0              1                       20       2017-08-17  1
7     0              2                       18       2017-08-17  1
```

So my final result while implementing the count should be

```
manag_id          count
1                 2
2                 5
```

I have read a lot, but could not find the exact solution. The only solution that comes to my mind is inner query.

Comment: Have you tried a query yet?

Comment: what are theses 2  and 5 counts based on ?

Comment: Why doesn't manager `0` appear in your expected output?

Comment: @RootIngenious The total comes from either manager_id field or on_behalf_manager_id so if a field is zero we can take the other one..

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen actually if the manager is zero then we need to select the value from the other field which is on_behalf_manager_id. Also check my previous comment. Hope it lets you understand the scenario. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure if this fits your needs, but maybe this guides you into the right direction:

```
SELECT
    CASE
WHEN manager_id = 0 THEN
    on_behalf_manager_id
ELSE
    manager_id
END AS manag_id,
 count(
    CASE
    WHEN manager_id = 0 THEN
        on_behalf_manager_id
    ELSE
        manager_id
    END
) AS count
FROM
    feedback
GROUP BY
    CASE
WHEN manager_id = 0 THEN
    on_behalf_manager_id
ELSE
    manager_id
END
```